# TLS 1.3 Support with WinINet API

Tags: wininet, tls1.3

Using WinINet family API (InternetConnect, HttpOpenRequest and more) to download files. Migrating application to support TLS 1.3 and found no way to support TLS 1.3 with WinINet.

Tried changing registry settings like -
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client

It didn't change anything. Have the option to use WinHTTP API or OpenSSL and it will be additional effort to rewrite code which I would like to avoid because of limited time.
Let me know if there are any options to enable TLS 1.3 with WinInet family API's.

Answer (score 0):

For TLS 1.2 there war a registry setting:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp]
"DefaultSecureProtocols "=dword:0x00000A00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"DefaultSecureProtocols "=dword:0x00000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"DefaultSecureProtocols "=dword:0x00000A00
```

The values are based on the following table:

| DefaultSecureProtocols Value | Protocol | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00000008 | Enable SSL 2.0 | by default |
| 0x00000020 | Enable SSL 3.0 | by default |
| 0x00000080 | Enable TLS 1.0 | by default |
| 0x00000200 | Enable TLS 1.1 | by default |
| 0x00000800 | Enable TLS 1.2 | by default |

Take the value for TLS 1.1 (0x00000200) and the value for TLS 1.2 (0x00000800) then add them together in calculator (in programmer mode), the resulting registry value would be 0x00000A00.

So I would guess `0x00002000` is the value for TLS 1.3.